# Why is the url parameter encoded?

Tags: apex, pagereference

Let's say I have a map object which will be converted into URL parameter.

`Map<String, Object> params = new Map<String, Object>{'accountId' => '0x10'}`

https://test.com/sample_vf_page_name?accountId=%220x10%22

I don't get how come it show %22 in the url parameters. How could I get rid of this issue from Salesforce

```
    Map<String, String> mapObj = new Map<String, String>();
    mapObj.put(paramName, paramValue);
    for (String key : extraParameters.keySet()) {
        mapObj.put(key, JSON.serialize(extraParameters.get(key)));
    }
    PageReference pageReference = new PageReference(redirectUrl);
    pageReference.getParameters().putAll(mapObj);
    return pageReference.getUrl();
```

Answer (score 3):

##Background:
URLs like "https://salesforce.stackexchange.com" can only contain certain characters.

The document that outlines this is [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)

From that, the following characters are allowed in a URL

> 2.3.  Unreserved Characters

> Characters that are allowed in a URI but do not have a reserved
> purpose are called unreserved.  These include uppercase and lowercase
> letters, decimal digits, hyphen, period, underscore, and tilde.

> ```
>  unreserved  = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
> ```

Where ALPHA = the latin alphabet (A-Z and a-z) and DIGIT is 0-9.

There are also characters like the colon `:`, forward-slash `/`, question mark `?` that have special meanings. These can appear in *some* places in the url, but not others.

Everything else needs to be escaped or encoded, and that RFC states that we do this by percent encoding the ascii value of the character we want to use.

In your case, the ascii value for a double quote is 22, so percent-encoded, that becomes `%22`.

**So, if you're seeing %22 in your url, then you must be introducing double quotes somewhere**

##Why is Salesforce doing this?
Salesforce is adding the single quotes to your Id string because you're JSON-encoding your parameters.

Using your example, and expanding on it...

```
// Pass #1, the "normal" method that will work as expected
Map<String, String> mapObj = new Map<String, String>();
mapObj.put('accountId', '001000000000000AAA');

PageReference pageReference = new PageReference('/account/');
pageReference.getParameters().putAll(mapObj);

system.debug(mapObj);
system.debug(pageReference.getUrl());

// Pass #2, JSON encoding
// Will introduce your double quotes
mapObj = new Map<String, String>();
mapObj.put('accountId', JSON.serialize('001000000000000AAA'));

pageReference = new PageReference('/account/');
pageReference.getParameters().putAll(mapObj);

system.debug(mapObj);
system.debug(pageReference.getUrl());
```

The result of running that is:

> 13:27:55:007 USER_DEBUG [76]|DEBUG|{accountId=001000000000000AAA}
> 13:27:55:007 USER_DEBUG [77]|DEBUG|/account/?accountId=001000000000000AAA
> Above is the result of the first portion of the code
> Below is the result of the second portion of the code
> 13:27:55:007 USER_DEBUG [83]|DEBUG|{accountId="001000000000000AAA"}
> 13:27:55:007 USER_DEBUG [84]|DEBUG|/account/?accountId=%22001000000000000AAA%22

A JSON string is enclosed in double quotes, which you can see is introduced on debug line 83 (the JSON-encoding example). Salesforce then dutifully percent-encodes those for you so your url is not invalid.

I seem to remember seeing something in the past couple of years that Unicode URLs or TLDs were being allowed or considered, but that doesn't have much bearing on my answer.